# Python String cleanup from spaces and Unknown empty element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I got attribute from Selenium Element and it contains empty char or spaces:
[image]

When I double click the result :
[image]

In VS code:
[image]

What I tried so far :

```
string.replace(" ","") #didnt work
```

So I came with this resolution (I know its bad ):

```
    edit1 = ticketID[:1]
    ticketF = ticketID.replace(edit1,"")

    edit2 = ticketF[:1]
    ticketE = ticketF.replace(edit2,"")

    edit3 = ticketE[:1]
    ticketD = ticketE.replace(edit3,"")
```

[image]

What Im looking for is what is those blanks ? tabs ? new lines ?
how to make it better ?

Edit:
[image]

```
ticketID.replace("\n","")
ticketID.replace(" ","")
ticketID.strip()
```

Comment: What code contains the 3781 ?

Comment: Its a element I got from a webpage check original post

Comment: Trimming is the solution to your problem. In Java, we use `String.trim()` method to remove any leading and trailing spaces. The alternative in Python is `strip()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are basically whitespaces, Please use `.strip()` for any trailing spaces.

In Python, the stripping methods are capable of **removing leading and trailing spaces** and specific characters. The leading and trailing spaces include `blanks`, `tabs` `(\t)`, carriage returns `(\r, \n)`, and the other lesser-known whitespace characters.

If you have `ele` as an `web element.`

You can use `.text` to get the text and then on top of that use `.strip()`

Probably in your code :

```
ticketID.text.strip()
```

Comment: `ticketID.strip()` didnt do the job

Comment: What is ticketID ? show  me in your code.

Comment: Also try with `ticketID.text.strip()` ? But I need to know what is `ticketID`, if it is an web element, the above updated code should work, if that is string directly use .strip on it.

Comment: Remove get_attribute and used - `ticketID.text.strip()` - Worked ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

They look like lines and not spaces to me.

```
string.replace("\n","")
```

Comment: `ticketID.replace("\n","")
ticketID.replace(" ","")
ticketID.strip()`
 - Nothing worked same result